# How to find name of column along with the maximum value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data(df_movies2) with columns: Year, production companies and revenue generated in that particular year. I want to return for each year, what is the maximum revenue along with the name of production companies. For example, in 2016 Studio Babelsberg has the maximum revenue. [This is the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjQ1P.jpg)

Here is what I have tried

```
  import pandas as pd 
df_movie2.groupby(['year','production_companies']).revenue.max()
```

But its not working returnning all the names of production companies for each year.
Thanks for your help

Comment: check out `groupby(column_name).revenue.max()`

Comment: I tried this and its not working, returning all the production companies name. Here is the code: df_movie2.groupby(['year','production_companies']).revenue.max

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in your question, including what you've tried so far and why it didn't work

Comment: `max()` not max

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're hoping to return. If your output is sorted as you want but you're missing values, it's because the `.max()` is dropping `duplicates` for your respective `year`. Please see edit 1 to return all values in ascending order from `max` to `min`.

If it's a sorting issue where you want to return the `max` value to `min` value and aren't worried about dropping `duplicate` `production_companies` for each `year` then refer to edit 2:

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'year' : ['2016','2016','2016','2016','2016','2015','2015','2015','2015','2014','2014','2014','2014'],        
    'production_companies' : ['Walt Disney Pictures','Universal Pictures','DC Comics','Twentieth Century','Studio Babelsberg','DC Comics','Twentieth Century','Twentieth Century','Universal Pictures','The Kennedy/Marshall Company','Twentieth Century','Village Roadshow Pictures','Columbia Pictures'],                 
    'revenue' : [966,875,873,783,1153,745,543,521,433,415,389,356,349],                                     
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Edit 1:

```
df = df.sort_values(['revenue', 'year'], ascending=[0, 1])
df = df.set_index(['year', 'production_companies'])
```

Output:

```
                                   revenue
year production_companies                 
2016 Studio Babelsberg                1153
     Walt Disney Pictures              966
     Universal Pictures                875
     DC Comics                         873
     Twentieth Century                 783
2015 DC Comics                         745
     Twentieth Century                 543
     Twentieth Century                 521
     Universal Pictures                433
2014 Twentieth Century                 389
     Village Roadshow Pictures         356
     Columbia Pictures                 349
     The Kennedy/Marshall Company      320
```

Edit 2:

```
df = df.groupby(['year','production_companies'])[['revenue']].max()
idx = df['revenue'].max(level=0).sort_values().index
i = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index.get_level_values(0), ordered=True, categories=idx)
df.index = [i, df.index.get_level_values(1)]
df = df.sort_values(['year','revenue'], ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
                                   revenue
year production_companies                 
2016 Studio Babelsberg                1153
     Walt Disney Pictures              966
     Universal Pictures                875
     DC Comics                         873
     Twentieth Century                 783
2015 DC Comics                         745
     Twentieth Century                 543
     Universal Pictures                433
2014 Twentieth Century                 389
     Village Roadshow Pictures         356
     Columbia Pictures                 349
     The Kennedy/Marshall Company      320
```